# Can't seem to resolve this hydration error nextjs 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <li> in <ul>. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

### Component Stack

#### li

#### ul

#### div

#### Todos

./src/components/Todos.tsx (15:118)

#### div

```
"use client"

import {useTodos} from "@/store/todos";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export  const Todos = () => {
 const {todos, toggleTodoAsCompleted, handleDeleteTodo} = useTodos();

 const searchParams = useSearchParams();
 const todosFilter = searchParams.get('todos')
    console.log("params " + todosFilter)

    let filteredTodos = todos;

    if (todosFilter === "active") {
        filteredTodos = todos.filter((todo) => !todo.completed);
    } else if (todosFilter === "completed") {
        filteredTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed);
    }

    return (<div>
        <p>List of todos</p>
        
        <ul className="main-task">
          
        {filteredTodos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={`todo-${todo.id}`}
              checked={todo.completed}
              onChange={() => {
                console.log(todo.completed);
                toggleTodoAsCompleted(todo.id);
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`todo-${todo.id}`}>{todo.task}</label>
            {todo.completed && (
              <button type="button" onClick={() => handleDeleteTodo(todo.id)}>
                Delete
              </button>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
}
```

changed the ul and li to div and section went to the docs and read about the cause still can't fix it "[Common Causes](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#common-causes)

Hydration errors can occur from:

1. Incorrect nesting of HTML tags

   1. `<p>` nested in another `<p>` tag
   2. `<div>` nested in a `<p>` tag
   3. [Interactive Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#interactive-content-2) cannot be nested (`<a>` nested in a `<a>` tag, `<button>` nested in a `<button>` tag, etc)
2. Using checks like `typeof window !== 'undefined'` in your rendering logic
3. Using browser-only APIs like `window` or `localStorage` in your rendering logic
4. [Browser extensions](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24430) modifying the HTML
5. Incorrectly configured [CSS-in-JS libraries](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js)

   1. Ensure your code is following [our official examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples)
6. Incorrectly configured Edge/CDN that attempts to modify the html response, such as Cloudflare [Auto Minify](https://developers.cloudflare.com/speed/optimization/content/auto-minify/)

"

Comment: Can you share the value of `filteredTodos`?

Comment: Can you show the server component where `<Todos />` is being called?

Answer (score 0):

its seems that the error i comming from the component that you are displaying this component on, the parent component is probably a server component, while the child component require user interaction, t
to solve this issue you can add a component like this  to your components folder and using it in your parent component :

```
    "use client";
    import {  useEffect, useState } from "react";
    function ClientOnly({ children, ...delegated }) {
    const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
    }, []);
    if (!hasMounted) {
    return null;
    }
    return <div {...delegated}>{children}</div>;
    }
    export default ClientOnly;

// parent component


   import ClientOnly from "../components"
   import Todos from "../components"

   // ....
   return (
   <>
   // ......
   <ClientOnly>
    <Todos/>
   <ClientOnly/>
   // .....
   </>
   };
```

The ClientOnly component will tell your app always to keep whatever rendred on the client whish will help you solve the hydration error.
hope this is helpfull.